# Asignar una fila de un vector a otro en c++

Tags: c++, ordenamiento

estoy haciendo un simple programa en c++. Necesito ordenar un vector por un valor en una columna que tengo en cada fila.

El método de ordenamiento es simple, pero no puedo hacer la asignación de la fila:

```
void PruebaVector2::ordenar()
{
    int i, j;
    int* temp;
    int alumno[3][2] = { { 1, 3 }, { 3, 5 }, { 1, 2 } };

    for (i = 0; i < 3 - 1 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (alumno[i][1] > alumno[j + 1][1])
            {
                temp = alumno[i];               
                alumno[i] = alumno[j];
                alumno[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Estoy ordenando por un método burbuja y al asignar `alumno[i] = alumno[j];` y `alumno[j] = temp;` me sale un error de asignación.

**Edicion**

`alumno[i] = alumno[j];` : error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
`alumno[j] = temp;` : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'char [3]'

Comment: Gracias @Mariano, ahí lo incluyo

Answer (score 1):

```
int* temp;
```

En la línea anterior estás definiendo un puntero a `int`. No tiene demasiado misterio esta línea. Todos sabemos que un puntero no es más que una referencia a una posición de memoria.

Los punteros en C++ no son inteligentes, no entienden el mundo que les rodea. Simplemente saben que apuntan a una dirección de memoria y ya. De hecho no hay forma de saber si la dirección apuntada por el puntero tiene un valor correcto o no.

Esto último te lo comento porque esta línea es incorrecta:

```
alumno[j] = temp;
```

Tu estás asumiendo que el puntero será lo suficientemente listo como para forzar la copia de toda la fila... pero la realidad es que el puntero no te va a ofrecer esa funcionalidad de forma implícita.

Para copiar la fila has de hacerlo elemento a elemento:

```
for( int k=0; k<2; k++ )
  alumno[j][k] = temp[k];
```

La única forma de forzar la copia automática de toda la fila es que la misma estuviese contenida dentro de una estructura o clase. De tal forma que al copiar dicho objeto se forzase la copia de toda la fila.

No te pongo códigos referentes a este tema porque entiendo que estás aprendiendo y esta parte de C++ queda fuera de lo que estás estudiando ahora mismo.

**EDITO:** No he sido demasiado explícito con la respuesta original. Lo que te he comentado de la asignación es aplicable a todas las ocasiones en las que intentas sobreescribir una fila con otra.

Si tu intención es sustituir una fila por otra puedes usar `std::swap` en vez de recurrir a almacenar los resultados en una variable temporal:

```
for( int k=0; k<2; k++)
  std::swap(alumno[i][k],alumno[j][k]);
```

Y si no, también hay formas de hacer sustituciones sin usar una variable temporal:

```
for( int k=0; k<2; k++)
{
  alumno[i][k] ^= alumno[j][k];
  alumno[j][k] ^= alumno[i][k];
  alumno[i][k] ^= alumno[j][k];
}
```

`^` es el operador XOR. Si conviertes los números a binario y realizas las 3 operaciones lo entenderás:

```
A = 10 = 1010
B = 3 = 0011

A = A^B = 1010 ^ 0011 = 1001
B = A^B = 1001 ^ 0011 = 1010 -> B = 10
A = A^B = 1001 ^ 1010 = 0011 -> A = 3
```